# STRONGN Strong Number (Special Numbers Series #2) word problem on Code Wars

Tags: c++, c++11

Strong number is the number that the sum of the factorial of its digits is equal to number itself.

For example: 145, since
1! + 4! + 5! = 1 + 24 + 120 = 145

Here is my code, It passes most of the test except one test

```
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

string strong_num (int number )
{
  int sum = 0;
  
  while(number != 0) {
    int last = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
    sum+= last * (last-1);
  }
  
  if(sum == number)
    return "STRONG!!!!";
  else
    return "Not Strong !!";
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised you're passing any test cases at all.  For one thing, you are destroying `number` before you compare it to `sum`, and for another your logic is flawed.

Try this:

```
int factorial (int x)
{
    int result = 1;
    while (x > 1)
    {
        result *= x;
        x--;
    }
    return result;
}

string strong_num (int number)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int x = number;
  
    while (x != 0) {
        int digit = x % 10;
        sum += factorial (digit);
        x /= 10;
    }
  
    if (sum == number)
        return "STRONG!!!!";
    else
        return "Not Strong !!";
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TAaBErMb9A1BKmrR)

Replace `int` by `long long` to be able to test larger numbers.

Comment: Paul knows this already so this is for those that follow: There aren't many factorials in the range 0..9. You can precompute them all, stuff them in a 10 element array and reduce a lot of the number crunching you need to do to an array look-up.

Comment: @user4581301 I know it, but I didn't think of it.  Nice idea, exercise for the reader.

Comment: Dang lol I guess I just need to get better at logic. I am such a terrible math person, but I love programming and love solving a problem. The only thing Is I struggle with most problems and I hope I get better at solving them.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:
first - you are changing the value of `number` before comparing it to `sum`,
second - the thing you used `last * (last-1)` is not a definition of factorial, the definition of factorial is `factorial(x) = 1 * 2 * 3 * ... * x`

```
int factorial (int x) {
    if(x < 2) return 1;
    return x * factorial(x - 1);
}

string strong_num (int number)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int x = number;
  
    while (x != 0) {
        int last = x % 10;
        sum += factorial (last);
        x /= 10;
    }
  
    if (sum == number)
        return "STRONG!!!!";
    else
        return "Not Strong !!";
}
```